# Url Rewrite - Add Query String Too

Tags: url-rewriting

I want to rewrite all URLs like

```
www.example.com/pages/foo
```

into

```
www.example.com/go.php?q=foo
```

I did it by using the rule belove but I can't manage to pass the query as well.

```
RewriteRule     ^pages/(.*)$            /go.php?q=$1  [L]
```

I want to rewrite:

```
www.example.com/pages/foo?bar=baz
```

into

```
www.example.com/go.php?q=foo&bar=baz
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

URL: `/pages/foo?bar=baz`

```
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*) /go.php?q=$1 [QSA,L,R]
```

becomes: `/go.php?q=foo&bar=baz`

What's happening is:

- capture everything after the slash and store it in $1
- request the resource at /go.php?q= and add our captured value
- [R] changes the displayed URL (otherwise we'd see no change in the URL, though we'd hit the correct page)
- QSA indicates Query String Append, which is the missing link :)
- [L] means 'last rule': don't look for further matches

Hope that helps!

Helpful links:

- http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-rewriterule-and-query-string/
- http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

---

**A second option is:**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^pages/(.*) /go.php?q=$1&%1 [R]
```

- captures the whole query string as **%1**
- captures the URL after /path/ as **$1**
- assembles the substitution string and rewrites the URL

*"In addition to plain text, the Substition string can include*

- *back-references ($N) to the RewriteRule pattern*
- *back-references (%N) to the last matched RewriteCond pattern"*

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

Comment: true, sorry.. it seems the escaping is unnecessary in my example, too!